# joomla mvc component redirect with friendly url

Tags: php, joomla, friendly-url

I got a code like this in my controller

```
class MyController extends MyBaseController {

 function redirectToCart() {
    $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_foo&view=cart');
    $this->setRedirect($link);
  }

}
```

I also created a menu associated with my view cart in menu name "View Cart" every time i click this button the url is `domainname.com/view-cart` but when use redirect in mvc the url is `domainname.com/index.php?option=com_foo&view=cart`

How can i create a redirect in mvc that it work with the front-end link or at least create a user friendly url

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `Itemid` in url to create desired seo:

```
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_foo&view=cart&Itemid=your_itemid');
```

You should turn of SEO and look what `Itemid` is in your menu item a use it in your url.

Or you can do it dynamically like this:

```
$itemid = JRequest::getint( 'Itemid' );
```

Then the `$link` would look:

```
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_foo&view=cart&Itemid='.$itemid);
```

Or you can take it from whatewer menu item you want like this:

```
$item = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getItem( $menuitem );//$menuitem is the id of menu
$itemid = $item->id;
```

Comment: I thought there must be a dynamic way to do this. I am using this method right now. but it is not seem right to me because every times I use this extension I need to manually insert the Id into the code.

Comment: But this way i still need to know $menuitem. if i move my menu or delete it and created somewhere else i still need to go to the code to have it url friendly